# z-index out ot context

Tags: css, z-index

This is simplified markup:

```
<div id="container">
        <div id="top" style="position:fixed">
            <div class="header-top" style="z-index:100"></div>
            <div id="access" style="z-index:100"></div>
            <div id="image" style="z-index:50"></div>
        </div><!--end top-->
        <div id="main" style="z-index:75"></div>
    </div>
```

as `#main` scrolls up over the fixed `#top` element, I would like it to display layered above `#image`, but below `#access` and `.header-top`.

Since the fixed position of `#top` creates a context, it seems I have a problem.

any thoughts?

Comment: are you making your element positionned or not? fixed position will not create a context if no z-index is set to it

Comment: @TemaniAfif  It's my understanding that fixed positioning sets a context for all z-index within it and excludes external elements from that context.

Comment: not in all the cases, share your full code .. we need all the code. Actually your code reproduce nothinh simply because the element aren't positionned thus z-index will not work

Answer (score -1):

You need to insert your `<div id="main">` inside `<div id="top">` after all.
You can create specific class for a fixed elements.

```css
#access, #main, #image {
            width:200px;
            height: 200px;                
}
.fixed {
            position:fixed;
    }
#access {
            background-color:red;
            margin: 100px 0 0 100px;
    }
#main {
            background-color:blue;
            margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
            position:absolute;        
    }
#image {
       background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="top">
        <div class="header-top fixed" style="z-index:100"></div>
        <div id="access" class="fixed" style="z-index:100"></div>
        <div id="image" class="fixed" style="z-index:50"></div>
        <div id="main" style="z-index:75"></div>
    </div><!--end top-->    
</div>
```